# Circumventing a "freemail" account form filter

Tags: penetration-test, email, privacy

I'll be honest - I want to download a free PDF from a website which requires me to enter my "non freeware" email address. I do have them, but I dont want to use one as I'm afraid of landing up on a spammer's list and having a hard time getting out.

How can I circumvent this filter and yet have a valid / email-able email address?

THe site is using a php script to check, no javascript... :(

Comment: Is this really a valid question for IT Security?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd agree that you're likely to end up having your email address distributed when signing up for something like this.

My preference, in order:

1. A disposable address, as suggested by Karrax.  These domains are often blocked, unfortunately.
2. If you have the ability though a non-free mail address, add an alias.  That way you can delete it when you no longer need it, or when it starts to get spam, but until then, you can still receive confirmation emails and the like.  (This is how I personally manage sites that ask for email addresses.  I've accidentally discovered that it's also a *really* good way to figure out when a site has been hacked and email addresses stolen.)
3. A dedicated web email address.   This is an email address that you use whenever you need to sign up on the web, you check when you know you have a confirmation email or download link, and just ignore the spam that it collects the rest of the time.
4. The GMail style +suffix.  I don't like this option as well, because it exposes your real email address to anybody who's interested in looking, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I like #2 - that's quite a sensible approach...

Comment: +1 for #2, too. Just takes a couple of seconds if your have access to a mail server. If not, create a dump-all address on Google (#3) which you can use for stuff like that.

Answer (score 5):

I would try any of the **disposable mailboxes** in the list you can find here: [top-20-temporary-and-disposable-email-services](http://www.sizlopedia.com/2007/05/27/top-20-temporary-and-disposable-email-services/).

You can for instance send the mail too matt74tm@mailinator.com and then check your mail over at http://www.mailinator.com/ . Do remember that anyone can check this mail as well, so there is no privacy in this kind of solution.

The disposable mailboxes requires no signup or registration.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Mailinator](http://www.mailinator.com) or [Slopsbox](http://slopsbox.com) or any other free mailbox.

Mailinator lists alternative domain names on its front page, and new ones are added regularly.  Whenever I find that `mailinator.com` is blocked, I try one of the alternative domain names listed on its front page, and usually that one isn't blocked yet.

If that doesn't work, a last resort is to sign up for a webmail service, create a new account, and use that email address.

Answer (score 1):

if your mailserver supports + hacks or similar (like gmail does) you can mr.youraddress@service (which will all be routed to youraddress@) and any mail with the mr. will easily be identifiable.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think you are referring to the +suffix instead? http://ideas.dalezak.ca/2009/02/powerful-gmail-feature-adding-suffix-to.html